# How can I block F12 keyboard key in jquery for all my pages and elements?

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to stop inspect element to the maximum amount. I know I can't stop them but still I would really like to reduce the chance. So how do I block the <kbd>F12</kbd> keyboard key in all HTML elements?

Result: no one can access <kbd>F12</kbd> and get inspect element.

Comment: And what you will do for view page source? Why you want to block inspect element? even Google didn't.

Comment: Not all browsers even use F12 to open the developer tools. Also, jQuery is a JavaScript library, how could we write jQuery without JS?

Comment: .My bad, I meant doesn't use full javascript.! (Alexander O'Mara)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here `123` is the `keyCode` of <kbd>F12</kbd> which opens the Inspect Element screen in the browser. Adding a `keydown` event than only does `return false` for `123` will block the Inspect Element screen.

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 123) { // Prevent F12
        return false;
    } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 73) { // Prevent Ctrl+Shift+I        
        return false;
    }
});
```

Prevent Right Click > Inspect Element

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", function (e) {        
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m9c771LL/5/)**

Comment: I can still Right click and then Click Inspect element :)

Comment: 1.Still if i press Control+shift+i -> It opens developer panel .
2.Also , top right square in chrome -> More tools -> Developer tools ,it opens .

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Sorry for that I have no idea.

Comment: We cant control whatever is Outside browser window :) . At least you tried your best to eliminate all possibilities Inside browser window. !

Comment: test on execution(right down) window not in coding window

Comment: @PratikCJoshi You can't block the client to use the F12 debugger, but this is perfect answer is to question  and even **Internial**  knows it's not possible

Comment: Along with this solution, try to open your content in a new window like this - `window.open(YOUR_URL, 'windowName', 'location=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=1,status=1,toolbar=0,fullscreen=1,channelmode=1');`

Comment: If @Sadikhasan answer is not working then add below code to your global js file      document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent right click 
}, false);

document.onkeydown = function (event) {  
 event = (event || window.event);  
 if (event.keyCode == 123) {  // Prevent F12
  return false;  
 } else if(event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 73) { // Prevent Ctrl+Shift+I
  return false;
 }
}

Comment: But what about [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[J]?

Answer (score 12):

add below script in your file, in head section after Jquery.js file

```
     <script language="JavaScript">
      
       window.onload = function () {
           document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
           }, false);
           document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
               //document.onkeydown = function(e) {
               // "I" key
               if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 73) {
                   disabledEvent(e);
               }
               // "J" key
               if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 74) {
                   disabledEvent(e);
               }
               // "S" key + macOS
               if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
                   disabledEvent(e);
               }
               // "U" key
               if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 85) {
                   disabledEvent(e);
               }
               // "F12" key
               if (event.keyCode == 123) {
                   disabledEvent(e);
               }
           }, false);
           function disabledEvent(e) {
               if (e.stopPropagation) {
                   e.stopPropagation();
               } else if (window.event) {
                   window.event.cancelBubble = true;
               }
               e.preventDefault();
               return false;
           }
       }
//edit: removed ";" from last "}" because of javascript error
</script>
```

Comment: This answer would be best if you included ctrl + c code as well,

Comment: @SybghatallahMarwat May I know the reason for ctrl+c here?

Comment: @AsadNaeem It will become a full package to control all set of keys.

Comment: @SybghatallahMarwat can u elaborate with some example?

Comment: No sir. you have to understand it that way

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my two cents. **You can't completely disable** those options but you can limit the ease of usage.

`onkeydown` actions are pretty rare from a user standpoint. One could even argue that the only real use case scenario would be, form completion.

Taking that approach the most effective way would be to conditionally disable the event itself with an exception to specific targets, in our case, `input`s and `textarea`s.

```js
document.onkeydown=function(e){if(!e.target.matches("input")&&!e.target.matches("textarea"))return!1};
```

A minimal and effective way of implementing this solution is to associate it with the `<body>` tag.

In the following example, in addition, I've added other behavior that are usually disabled when thinking of user ability restrictions (eg: user selection, dragging, right-click).

```html
<body onkeydown="if(!event.target.matches('input')&&!event.target.matches('textarea'))return!1" oncontextmenu="return!1" onselectstart="return!1" ondragstart="return!1">
```