# Disable F12 in IE9 using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

How to disable or block F12 button in Internet Explorer 9 using Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Not sure you can stop someone from using a part of the browser that has nothing to do with the web content - at least, I hope you can't! ... have you tried listening for key events

Comment: Yes, I tried it.. but no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I block f12 keyboard key in jquery for all my pages and elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575722/how-can-i-block-f12-keyboard-key-in-jquery-for-all-my-pages-and-elements)

Answer (score 1):

> Here 123 is the keycode of the F12 key, which prevents from opening the Inspect Element screen in the browser. On keyDown return false that does not open Inspect Element screen.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode==123){
    return false;
   } else if(event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode==73){        
      return false;  //Prevent from ctrl+shift+i
   }
});
```

Prevent Right Click Inspect Element

```
$(document).on("contextmenu",function(e){        
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Of course someone who knows enough to inspect elements can disable that in about, oh, 5.8 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have already tried this code. It is working fine in chorme, mozilla, IE 8 but It is not working in IE 9!